# Flexslider invisible

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I recently started using flexslider.

I'm creating a website using bootstrap, and using code to embed flexslider images become **invisible** and I have no result.

In **header**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexslider.css"> 
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

In **custom.js**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
```

In the **body**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li><img src="img/img1.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="img/img2.png" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A the end of the body

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

This is my code

Can anyone explain why?

**Thanks** in advance

Comment: i have the same problem :-/ have you found a solution?

Comment: Same thing here. The script definitely starts. I placed an alert right after $.flexslider = function(el, options) { and it fired.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the flexslider you mention. A plugin with name "flexslider" was not findable on the jQuery plugins page.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/dilet/1 is working fine for me as expected. @Marcel, the flexslider homepage is http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: Are you loading the Flexslider CSS after the Bootstrap CSS? Otherwise, the styling may be getting overwritten.

That being said, inspect the slide elements in your browser to see what CSS rules are being applied. If the script is loading properly, sounds like it might just be a CSS issue

Answer (score 0):

There must be some jquery version issue and you missed bootstrap.css as well. I have made fiddle of flexslider which is working perfect. just have look at it : http://jsfiddle.net/7ngoLbxw/1/

```js
$('.flexslider').flexslider();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: block; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;"><img src="http://wallpaperiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/live-wallpapers-for-desktop-widescreen-7-cool.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
                <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: block; z-index: 2; opacity: 1;" class="flex-active-slide"><img src="http://www.wallpaper.in.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Live-Wallpapers-For-Desktop-Free-Download1.jpg" draggable="false"></li>
            </ul>
        <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a class="">1</a></li><li><a class="flex-active">2</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li><li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul></div>
    </div>
</div>
```